# Getting Error -4048 when trying to run Playwright scripts

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to set up a playwright script to take some screenshots and I've been getting this error:

```
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\elevateddiagnostics'] {
  errno:-4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  Syscall: 'scandir', 
  path h:'c:\\users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\ElevatedDiagnostics'
}
```

Currently none of my test scripts are working, including the example one. What might the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

`npm init playwright@latest`
solved the problem for me.